# MySQL - Select 1 for each X rows

Tags: mysql, database, where-clause

I have a database with the some fields including `id` and `store_id`. `id` is AI and `store_id` an int between 0 and 7.

My goal is to select for example 1 for each 2 rows, so i'd get row id=0, id=2, id=4 .. etc. I could do that with:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE MOD(id,2)=0
```

but my problem is that i that `store_id` because i wanted to get 1 for each x rows `WHERE store_id=y`

Can you help me with this? If you need any other detail feel free to ask, thanks

Comment: please explain your question?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE MOD(id,2)=0 AND store_id=y`?

Comment: @ring0 This does not work exactly as he want, what about having all "store_id=y" odd ? or all even ?

Comment: @Julien can "he" talk? :-) If you understood the question better than me (that's not difficult) please go ahead...

Comment: sorry, i was making this: http://pastebin.com/pXaCANja

Comment: @ring0 Your're right, I probably misundersood (or rushed), and your solution may fit, let him talk ;-) sorry !

Comment: @ring0 unfortunatly your solution wont work because it will exclude all odd rows, even if their STORE_ID is y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MOD(id, 2) = 0 AND store_id = y
```

Seems an idea, but what about having all "store_id = y" having odd id's ?

So, what about running a subquery to apply filters, adding a counter to results, and then filter over the counter :

```
set @counter = 0;
SELECT id, store_id FROM
(
    SELECT id, store_id,
    @counter := @counter + 1 as counter
    FROM foo WHERE store_id = 2
) AS sub
WHERE MOD(counter, 2) = 0
```

Comment: i dont know all the concepts here, but i'll take a look at that now, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, that works ! I'd upvote you, but i dont have enough reputation yet

Comment: done :) but i'm having a problem, cant i use those variables (@counter) in a PHP mysql_query() ?

Comment: Didn't tried with PHP, mysql_query can only execute one request at a time, humm ... try two different mysql_queries, first to set @counter, 2nd to execute request (split at ';')