# Select Sum of 5 Values from every 50 rows and group by the sum

Tags: mysql

I am trying to analyse some data by sampling it by grabbing 5 values from every 50 rows and summing them together.

The data looks like this -

```
Col 1
    177
    177
    177
    177
    174
    174
    174
    166
    166
    166
    166
    170
    170
    170
    170
    171
    171
    171
    171
    174
    174
    174
    174
    168
    168
    168
    168
    172
    172
    172
    172
    172
    171
    171
    171
    171
    171
    171
    171
    170
    170
    170
    170
    170
    171
    171
    171
    174
    174
    174
    174
    171
    171
    171
    171
    169
    169
    169
    169
    169
    171
    171
    171
    172
    172
    172
    172
    171
    171
    171
    171
    171
    171
    171
    171
    171
    171
    171
    171
    171
    171
    171
    171
    171
    171
    171
    171
    171
    171
    171
    171
    172
    172
    172
    172
    170
    170
    170
    170
    171
```

I could manage this by using a UNION but it looks really messy and wondered if there was any nice solution to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675595/mysql-select-1-for-each-x-rows Check this out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MySQL [User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) to get row numbers and group Numbers. This query returns sum of 5 values of each 50. I've added ID filed to order these values you should use ORDER BY your identity filed to order values.

```
SELECT GroupID, 
       SUM(Col1) as SumOfCol1 
FROM
(
 SELECT T.*,
       @counter := IF(@counter>=50,1,@counter + 1) as counter,
       @GroupID := IF(@counter=1,@GroupId + 1,@GroupId) as GroupID
 FROM T, 
     (SELECT @counter :=0,@GroupID := 0) r
 ORDER BY ID  
) T1 
WHERE Counter<=5
GROUP BY GroupID
```

<kbd>[SQL fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/691af/4)</kbd>

Answer (score -2):

```
select sum(data) from
(
select distinct data from table limit 0,50;
union
select distinct data from table limit 50,50;
union
select distinct data from table limit 100,50;
union
select distinct data from table limit 150,50;
)temp;
```

This will take distinct data from given limit in subquery.
main query sums it up.

Comment: I know I could use a union, but the data I am using can consist of tens of thousands of rows.. I would be writing a query about 10000 lines long.